# BaseTypeAttribute not found in a binding project

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to create Xamarin bindings for a Obj-C library. I'm following the provided guide from http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries

Everything goes well, OBjective Sharpie creates the interfaces and no error is reported. It is only when I try to compile the solution that the [BaseType] (BaseTypeAttribute class) is not found.

Does anybody knows what I'm missing?
Where is the BaseTypeAttribute class defined?

Thank,
Ignacio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The project was not compiling as I added the output of Sharpie to a new file.

You either use the provided ApiDefinition file or you have to set the Build Action to ObjCBindingApiDefinition

Answer (score 7):

API definition files are compiled using the btouch tool, not a C# compiler.   The btouch tool compiles your API definition against itself, where the type is defined.